# WebApi to create User not working from Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried to make new user in my sql azure in xamarin.android with web api. but i got this error message every time I try to create new user

```
{"$id":"1","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://xamari/nlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login'.","messageDetail":"No action was found
```

so this web api is provide to make authentication and create new user, my login is fine no error, but when I create new user I got that error message.

Here is my web api controller :

```
  using System;  
    using System.Collections.Generic;  
    using System.Linq;  
    using System.Net;  
    using System.Net.Http;  
    using System.Web.Http;  
    using XamarinLogin.Models;  
    namespace XamarinLogin.Controllers  
    [RoutePrefix("api/Login")]
    {  
        public class LoginController: ApiController  
        {  
            xamarinloginEntities db = new xamarinloginEntities();  
            /  
            [HttpPost]  
            [ActionName("XAMARIN_REG")]  
            // POST: api/Login  
            public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_reg(string username, string password)  
            {  
                Login login = new Login();  
                login.Username = username;  
                login.Password = password;  
                db.Logins.Add(login);  
                db.SaveChanges();  
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Successfully Created");  
            }  
            [HttpGet]  
            [ActionName("XAMARIN_Login")]  
            // GET: api/Login/5  
            public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_login(string username, string password)  
            {  
                var user = db.Logins.Where(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();  
                if (user == null)  
                {  
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Please Enter valid UserName and Password");  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Success");  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

and this is my create user script in xamarin.android :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace LoginAzureDroid
{

    public class NewUserActivity : Activity
    {
        EditText txtusername;
        EditText txtPassword;
        Button btncreate;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create your application here  
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Reg);
            txtusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtsaveusername);
            txtPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtsavepassword);
            btncreate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnsavecreate);
            btncreate.Click += Btncreate_Click;
        }
        private async void Btncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login log = new Login();
            log.username = txtusername.Text;
            log.password = txtPassword.Text;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = "http://xamarinlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login";
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                var errorMessage1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\\", "").Trim(new char[1]
                {
                '"'
                });
                Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage1, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                var errorMessage1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\\", "").Trim(new char[1]
                {
                '"'
                });
                Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage1, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so what is my fault in here, is it my url ? my code in web api ? or my code in xamarin.android.

Comment: help anyone please

Comment: May it be your URL ?`http://xamari/nlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login` I can't imagine someone would split xamarin into ( xamari / n )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {"$id":"1","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://xamari/nlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login'.","messageDetail":"No action was found

Based on your code, you added the **RoutePrefix** for your `LoginController`, I assumed that you need to add Route Attribute for each or your actions as follows:

```html
[HttpPost]  
[Route("XAMARIN_REG")]  
// POST: api/Login/XAMARIN_REG
public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_reg(string username, string password)
```

```html
[HttpGet]  
[Route("XAMARIN_Login")]  
// GET: api/Login/XAMARIN_Login?username={username}&password={password}
public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_login(string username, string password)
```

For creating a new user, you need to change the url as follows:

```
string url = "http://xamarinlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login/XAMARIN_REG";
```

Also, you could refer to [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more details.

**UPDATE:**

You could define a view model for user registration as follows:

```html
public class RegUser
{
  public string username {get;set;}
  public string password {get;set;}
}

[RoutePrefix("api/Login")]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("regUser")]
    public string newUser(RegUser user)
    {
        return user.username + "_" + user.password;
    }
}
```

[image]

Additionally, here is a blog about [pass multiple parameters to Web API controller methods](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3136743/application-development/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-web-api-controller-methods.html), you could refer to it for multiple approaches.

Comment: Do you get the same error about action is not found or new error message, could you provide the detailed info?

Comment: no the error message is "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://xamarinlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login'."

Comment: so its not about action, but i think its the HTTP resource or something

Comment: I assumed that the request url with the specific http verb could not be routed to the correct action. Please check my update and try to check with it. Also, have you [Enabling Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enabling-attribute-routing)?

Comment: or maybe is there a chance this error caused by my sql database, because i think my id column is primarykey but not auto increments ?

Comment: I have checked with this issue again, for “Action is not found”, I have updated my answer with my test, you could refer to it. Also, you could refer to apineda's answer.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem but i solved the issue.

**Solve:**

```
string url = "http://xamarinlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login/XAMARIN_REG/username=" + user.username+ "&password=" + user.password";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API endpoint is expecting the values (username and password) to be sent in the url but you are sending them in an object called `Login` and in the body of the post. This is the reason an **Action is not found**

To fix this you either change your API signature to reflect what I explained above or you change the code in the Mobile App to something like

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username",  txtusername.Text}, { "password", txtPassword.Text } };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent (parameters);

response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

Also as a suggestion, when using `HttpClient` for a single HTTP operation try to always dispose the object once you finish. You can get this by using the `using` clause like this:

```
string url = "http://xamarinlogin20170612105003.azurewebsites.net/api/Login";
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    ....

    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);

    ....
}
```

Comment: so i dont need to change my api ?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang  I gave you two options. Option 1 You would need to change your API (refer to the answer by Bruce). Option 2; You don't need to change your API as you will be sending what the API is expecting.